# Rejected Candidate showing up to the office

Tags: employer

We do interviews then send selected candidates to panel interviews.

Considering the following scenario:

If an applicant comes into the building after they receive a rejection letter, and asks you in person why they were not selected to continue on in the interviewing process.

What would be a suitable response or course of action if this happens?

Comment: Is this a thing that happened?

Comment: This seems awfully vague. Depends on details, how the applicant is behaving and their age and sex, location, what is the office like and who are present... Any answer can't be anything but speculation.

Comment: Ask them to leave and tell them you will call security of not.

Comment: funny how no one is even considering simply telling the person the truth. Has truth gone out of style in XXI century?

Comment: @LechRzedzicki Yes, truth is a good strategy if you have a reasonable person. However, if somebody goes through the effort to come in person, they can be merely ambitious in the best case (in which a fair response is right), but equally possible is that they are desperate, or obsessed - with potential outcomes that may end in court or worse.

Comment: What's your role in this? Are you the recruiter, interviewer, hiring manager?

Comment: It sounds like the candidate is young and does not understand how business operates. Eventually he or she will realize companies cannot be trusted, and any answer is probably a distortion or a lie.

Comment: @LechRzedzicki I suggested it but my answer was heavily downvoted. Apparently the correct response is to call the cops and hide under a desk while perusing your company's terrorism response plan.

Answer (score 41):

First, the person would actually have to get into the building. To do this, they typically need to pass the front desk, and there is no reason for the front desk to let them in. That's neither rude nor inappropriate, but perfectly normal when someone shows up without an appointment for whatever reason (interview related or not). "Sorry, the people you want to see are busy".

If they try to force their way in, call security or the police.

Comment: Ask them to leave. If they don't, call security or the police.

Comment: You can't know how hard it is to get into the particular building or office premises, so this answer appears to be just speculative.

Comment: @DavidThornley: then they are trespassing. If someone would show up at my desk unannounced I'd escort them out of the building and have charges filed. Hasn't happened once in my 30+ years. Most front desks know how to do their jobs

Comment: I've snuck into offices before, on multiple occasions (for non-nefarious reasons obviously). It isn't hard.

Comment: I wonder what the percentage of offices with an actual front desk really is.

Comment: @Mär: most offices either have a dedicated front desk or some process how to answer the door when the door bell rings. They are not going to leave the front door open and unattended for anyone to walk in they please.

Comment: @NathanCooper what non-nefarious reason could you have to sneak into an office, bypassing security? Doing their dishes for them?

Comment: I'm wondering what kind of companies you guys are all working for. Here at my company (~100 people) we have no front desk and normally no one is caring about the door bell. It would be easy to simply walk in and do whatever you want

Comment: Yeah, most companies don't really have a front desk or legal or even HR. Thing is, we think of a white collar office job, when we hear company. But the majority of companies out there are tiny businesses with a handful of people.

Answer (score 24):

Give them no information. If they press, refer them to the information in the rejection letter or refer them to contact the recruiter they were working with at your company (assuming it wasn't you). If there are signs that make you uncomfortable, **do not hesitate to call your building security or the local police or law enforcement.**

Giving **ANY** information is not going to benefit you personally or your employer. Your employer has already covered all the bases they care about in the rejection letter. That process exists for a purpose, you should respect that. Giving the candidate info likely won't benefit the candidate, either - if they're not fit for the job, giving them info on why won't suddenly get them hired. And if they want to "improve for the future" they certainly can, and should, focus on getting employment support elsewhere (ie a third party recruiter, job training, etc), *not* from an employer who has rejected them. **Your obligation to interact with this individual ended when they got the rejection letter.**

Job interviews and hiring processes can be stressful on candidates, and can bring out the worst in people who aren't equipped to handle the stress. You don't know their mental state or how they handle negative feedback, and in a situation where they've just randomly shown up and confronted you, they're already showing signs that they may not be the most stable, by-the-book person. **Think of your own personal safety first** and do what you can to de-escalate, end the discussion, and get outside help from security or police as needed.

Comment: And this is just _one_ reason why interviewers generally do not give out their contact information to the interviewee.  (Though sometimes it is easily guessable or discoverable, like an email address.)  The interviewer is _not_ the one on the hook for the legal elements that must be considered, nor is he typically trained on it - but if he volunteers something to the rejected candidate then he _may become so_, and there's no upside to him for that!

Answer (score 7):

Provide feedback if you feel comfortable doing so. If you don't simply say you can't divulge that information or give them some sort of canned answer like "we felt other candidates were better suited for this position" and usher them out the door. If you're worried this candidate might get angry and come back with a machine gun or something then alert the appropriate authorities.

Comment: This answer seems the best. Even though it is not a typical behaviour for companies, every candidate should have the right to know why they were rejected -- ideally in their rejection letter. I wouldn't think upfront that such person is a threat or in a bad mental state or talking about weapons... Major words. I would say: try to address its request if you can and be polite to that person while doing so. Then, when leaving, apologise and make sure s/he leaves.

Comment: @Kiddo "every candidate should have the right to know why they were rejected"  Companies tend not to elaborate because it opens them up to all kinds of legal liability if the candidate doesn't like the answer.

Comment: @Blrfl: allowing them to know that they failed the interview because they were deemed not fit because of X (e.g., one of the requisites of the offer) or they failed an assignment because of Y (they did wrong this or that). These are objective replies that I fail to see how they could be used legally to claim anything like damage or abuse. Instead, it provides clarity on the process. They (should) have some KPIs, the candidate did not meet some of them. I know that in some kind of countries they love tending to legal matters, but even so I fail to see how they could "corrupt" such replies.

Comment: Providing specific feedback is a dangerous, slippery slope, which is why many (most?) employers won't do so, directly to a candidate. There's nothing for the employer to gain, and by saying anything specific, you're opening yourself up for potential backlash (ie you unintentionally give them ammo for a discrimination lawsuit).

Comment: Agree with @Blrfl on this, the company has zero upside and only potential downsides to even having this conversation. A rejected candidate randomly showing up at the office is very abnormal behavior, and is not the type of person you want to give any possible legal fodder to.

Comment: @Kiddo - this guy shows up _at the office_ to ask why he was rejected?  When has that _ever_ been acceptable behavior?  It's definitely a red flag - it may not be an _actual_ threat but it is surely a _caution_ you can't ignore.  The person has a _contact number_ or _email_ for the recruiter or maybe the hiring manager: His question is _properly_ asked by email or over the phone.  Not in person.

Comment: Sure, the company has nothing to gain and they don't care. It is not common that a rejected candidate asks for real feedback (which they won't be given anyway by mail or phone / cc @davidback), yet this becomes definitely more possible from the very moment an org. is not honestly handling rejections (this, or negative feedback on glassdoor or friend-to-friend). That's what they reap after a "polite" but not "kind" reply; and my comment is aimed to alleviate the problem after the company did a wrong. They can do the same and call security, but that seems just another patch.

Comment: @Kiddo Blrfl is saying that often companies, their own included, reject candidates based on sex/sexuality/race/etc. and don't want to be held responsible for it. Expecting them to make up a reason for every candidate is just too much effort.

Comment: @Kiddo 'candidates should have the right ...'. They don't.

Comment: @Time4Tea I know the current "state of the art". That's why the "should" part is in place, isn't it? Nevertheless, we will not agree on what is, to some of us, an ethical obligation of providing feedback in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Where I work, they would be able to enter the building (yes, you can enter the building, and sit on a sofa, for example if it rains outside), but they wouldn't be able to enter the stairs or the lift or any office. They might be able to sneak in though and make it to our office door which involves following through at least two further doors.

They could then ring our door bell and someone would open the door. Not recognising them, they would ask who the person is and what the person wants, and not let them in. If the person pushes past them, I can tell you that you are in trouble which would involve police. If the person doesn't, someone in management would be called to check. If nobody with management responsibility is there, it might be me or some other senior developer going to the door.

Whoever goes to the door would not let him in. The person would be told that it is inappropriate to appear at the office after being rejected in a job interview. They might be told that turning up like this indicates that the decision was right. If you came through some recruiting agency, the agency would be told.

Just don't do it. In the best case it's a waste of everyone's time and not going to help you, and in the worst case you get yourself into trouble, may be remembered, and may have problems with your recruiting agency.

Answer (score 0):

Your organisation should have a process for this. Usually the information they can be given is exactly the same as that they would have received in the letter turning them down, or also quite commonly they will be turned away unless they have an appointment.

In the UK we have a requirement to provide interview notes to the interviewer if they ask, but typically that is all.

Answer (score -7):

I think it goes without saying that this kind of behaviour is unusual and probably inappropriate in most cultures, but I don't think that needs to preclude giving the person the information that they're seeking. Perhaps even more so in this situation as the individual might not be aware that they're breaching social norms - in all likelihood their blind spots didn't help them during the interview process either.

You'd be well within your rights to turn them away, and in the absence of other responses I'd probably be emphasising that a bit more, but given the responses already cover this I'll focus on another option; using the time to explain your decision and what they can do to improve their chances in future might be a hugely valuable experience for the candidate. I think the likelihood of harm arising from having a conversation with them is overstated in the other responses.

I think the other answers are needlessly paranoid and too narrowly focused on solely fiduciary obligations. There are many innocent explanations for this behaviour and while a cursory assessment of their mental state wouldn't be a bad idea I also think the risk of some kind of violent derangement or an impending lawsuit at the slightest item of constructive feedback (which the other answers seem to be implying) is just plain silly.

Having said that, this conversation would be a good time to point out how inappropriate it is for them to show up like this, and that they would have improved their chances by simply calling or sending an email for further clarification. This feedback might be more important and useful to the candidate than any constructive commentary on their  interview performance.

I initially mentioned a disclaimer that I wasn't from the US, which I took out, but I'm starting to wonder whether the downvotes are related to a jurisdictional/cultural issue. I don't know whether the risk of someone arriving with a weapon or lawsuit are a realistic prospect elsewhere; they definitely are not where I am from.

Comment: -1 Someone  who things turning up in this fashion after already being rejected, shouldn't be indulged

Comment: @motosubatsu I fail to see why this is a big deal. Obviously it's not appropriate or socially acceptable, but I don't think that should necessitate being rude to them or locking them out of the building.

Comment: Why reward rude and entitled behaviour? All that will do is encourage it. I'm not saying you should be rude to them or lock them out, but politely and firmly turn them away.

Comment: @motosubatsu locking someone out of a building and refusing to talk to them on the basis that their behaviour is outside of social norms strikes me as more "rude and entitled" than what the candidate is doing.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but I think my explanation wasn't particularly good, so I've tried to clarify the rationale a bit. @motosubatsu I think your response is a bit arbitrary. Can you point to something other than social norms that would justify the way you're proposing to behave in this scenario?

Comment: I haven't suggested locking anyone out of a building, and it's rather a leap to get there from my words which were *"politely and firmly turn them away"*, and I'm not sure that I **need** much in the way of justification for that, but for the sake of clarity how about - I'm not going to waste any more of my company/my employer's time?

Comment: It's not about paranoia. It's about obligation - or lack thereof. The employer initiated this whole process (by advertising the job). The employer has decided the process is over - with this candidate. Spending time or energy "helping" a candidate that's already been rejected is a waste of employer resources at this point. If the candidate really wants to understand their weaknesses, they need to pursue appropriate channels: this employer is not a charity to help them better themselves.

Comment: I suppose if you're both saying that the employer's actions should end with their obligations, then your answers are right. I happen to disagree with the premise though.

Comment: @dwizum what channels are you referring to?

Comment: As I'm not finding the rationale for downvoting this to be very convincing I'm going to leave this answer up for now. I've tried to take the responses from both of you into account by editing my question a bit - let me know what you think of the new wording. It's fundamentally the same answer but I've tried to clarify that my response is really about what can be done _in excess_ of the obligations, as opposed to just clarifying what the requirements are in this situation. This recognises that my response is more subjective.

Comment: You don't see harm in a potential lawsuit? Yes, it's a worst case. But the best case is a waste of time so you're not missing out on anything. I'd never ever want to re-consider a candidate who behaves like this. The reason people are down-voting is because your answer is bluntly dangerous.

Comment: Go to a career fair, show your resume to recruiters, ask for feedback. Find a third party recruiter that focuses on your field, do a mock interview with them, discuss the positions you're interested in, and ask for feedback. If you are a college grad, get in touch with your school's careers office (most will work with you through your whole career, not just while you're enrolled). Look at feedback you've received at performance reviews in the past, make sure you're addressing gaps. Look for interview advice online - many candidates simply need to work on interviewing.

Comment: @Jonast92 I agree I probably wouldn't consider the candidate after such a situation, so I've removed that from my answer. I've added lawsuits to the reason why I think the other answers are silly/paranoid.

Comment: @dwizum I think I can answer you question with another one; do you think that someone who rocks up like this would be sufficiently well informed to meaningfully seek those other avenues?

Comment: I've also re-added a comment about the fact that I'm not from the US. I'm wondering if there are jurisdictional or cultural differences at play here.

Comment: @quant whether or not the candidate knows of other channels has no bearing on whether or not the employer (who, again, has already rejected the candidate) has *any* responsibility or obligation to educate the candidate on how to do better at getting a job. Weapons and lawsuits aside, the employer is not a charity, and they have *nothing to gain* by "helping" a candidate they've already rejected.

Comment: @dwizum I think you're stating the obvious with that last comment. We might have exhausted the point you're exploring as I think I've addressed it already. Agree to disagree?

Comment: I think there's another dangerous part of this answer.  Thinking "Is this person unhinged?  Should I be afraid?" for any random person you meet is paranoid.  Weighing that with someone who's violated social norms rather severely *isn't* paranoid.  Yeah, the person *probably* isn't unbalanced... but the *unlikeliness* of it is WAY less than just any random person.  They didn't follow the norm, and they didn't even ask via email - they showed up *in person*, *unannounced*.  The OP should absolutely be keeping "What's the likelihood of them being nuts?" in the back of their mind.

Comment: @Kevin I don't think what you've said is in disagreement with my response.

Comment: @quant - "I think the *likelihood of harm* arising from having a conversation with them is overstated in the other responses."  and "I think the other answers are *needlessly paranoid* and too narrowly focused on solely fiduciary obligations" and "I also think the *risk of some kind of violent derangement* or an impending lawsuit at the slightest item of constructive feedback are *just plain silly*."  You can't call it a silly, needlessly paranoid, low-likellhood worry... and then turn around and agree with someone saying it's not silly, not needlessly paranoid, and not unlikely.

Comment: _"I think the likelihood of harm arising from having a conversation with them is overstated in the other responses."_ is not contradicted by _"The OP should absolutely be keeping "What's the likelihood of them being nuts?" in the back of their mind"_. I think I make that clear in my post when I wrote _"a cursory assessment of their mental state wouldn't be a bad idea"_.

Comment: The top answer is very reasonable and I've voted for it, but the 2nd top answer by dwizum states _"Give them no information...Do not hesitate to call law enforcement"_. That's patently ridiculous - if he were a manager, think about what kind of environment that attitude would create in a workplace. It only makes sense if you accept the likelihood of violence as a significant risk by default, which I think is the crux of the disagreements here. The answer jumps straight to a vanishingly unlikely outcome as the primary driver for decision-making. That's paranoia.